# How to break apart a dashed curve in CorelDraw?

Tags: corel-draw

I want to draw a dashed-like shape that can be converted to svg properly. Usual way of drawing dashed-like shape is to draw a curve and turn its style to desire dashed style using Corel tools.

[image]

but when I convert this into svg and import it in Android as vector file, the dashed line become auto-closed, non-dashed and filled curve (as follow).

[image]

So I tried to break apart it and make each part a separated shape but, Break Apart option is disabled for such curves.

[image]

How one can break apart such dashed curve in CorelDraw?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a screen capture of two SVG I exported from Corel and viewed on a browser. Nothing really special.

[image]

We need to see the code.

The one on the left is a series of blocks with red fill and the one on the right is a path with a description of how to render the dashed stroke. We can see that in the generated code. I am only posting the path tag. There are a bunch of numbers but you can see the difference on the initial attributes of the file. (You can use them to reconstruct the examples)

Red:

```
<path fill="red" fill-rule="nonzero" d="M1255.59 2631.16c-209.78,-404.46 -439.32,-799.28 -724.4,-1155.91l-17.84 -21.94 -513.35 419.73c263.12,324.24 475.27,693.86 667.1,1063.71l588.49 -305.59zm9048.65 1029.82c-136.28,-258.26 -249.38,-532.48 -356.69,-803.89 -49.67,-126.2 -98.32,-252.8 -146.67,-379.52l-619.49 236.57c161.9,423.22 324.19,850.12 534.23,1252.26l1.6 3.03 587.02 -308.45zm-746.62 -1808.01c-115.18,-284.4 -240.28,-566.48 -391.03,-834 -82.51,-144.55 -173.88,-288.31 -278.69,-417.82l-514.37 418.5 -1.41 -1.76c82.39,104.1 151.92,213.07 217.68,328.23 136.41,242.1 249.38,499.44 353.61,756.81l614.21 -249.96zm-1314.33 -1760.69l-24.65 -9.76 -21.09 -7.86 -21.29 -7.51 -21.52 -7.15 -21.58 -6.73 -21.82 -6.38 -22.03 -6 -22.05 -5.57 -22.27 -5.19 -22.48 -4.8 -22.59 -4.4 -22.69 -3.97 -22.88 -3.57 -22.97 -3.15 -23.13 -2.74 -23.24 -2.31 -23.29 -1.89 -23.35 -1.45 -23.5 -1.06 -23.78 -0.61 -23.72 -0.18 -23.65 0.23 -23.89 0.65 -24.03 1.1 -23.97 1.52 -23.98 1.93 -24.19 2.36 -24.22 2.78 -24.16 3.19 -24.35 3.63 -24.35 4.04 -24.38 4.44 -24.47 4.87 -24.49 5.28 -24.58 5.69 -24.58 6.11 -24.54 6.48 -24.72 6.91 -24.67 7.31 -24.73 7.7 -24.92 8.15 -24.82 8.51 -24.82 8.89 -24.94 9.3 -25 9.7 -25.05 10.1 -25.12 10.51 -27.49 12.03 -27.1 12.54 -26.83 13.1 -26.5 13.63 -26.08 14.11 -25.68 14.56 -25.37 15.1 -24.99 15.56 -24.63 16.03 -24.24 16.5 -23.89 16.95 -23.44 17.34 -23.06 17.76 -22.71 18.2 -22.35 18.62 -21.96 19.01 -21.56 19.38 -21.15 19.72 -20.77 20.07 -10.25 10.27 473.27 464.47 14.29 -13.88 12.4 -11.56 12.45 -11.19 12.57 -10.88 12.65 -10.54 12.78 -10.24 12.94 -9.97 13.06 -9.66 13.12 -9.32 13.26 -9.02 13.42 -8.74 13.56 -8.45 13.73 -8.16 13.95 -7.92 14.09 -7.62 14.17 -7.29 14.43 -7.04 14.68 -6.79 14.87 -6.52 17.38 -7.26 17.13 -6.91 16.92 -6.57 16.68 -6.23 32.72 -11.47 15.84 -5.18 31.28 -9.5 15.21 -4.25 15.11 -3.99 14.8 -3.67 14.52 -3.37 28.44 -5.9 27.6 -4.81c13.3,-1.98 26.44,-3.71 39.8,-5.25l25.54 -2.28c97.32,-6.09 185.33,5.05 275.83,42.33l248.1 -614.95zm-2011.69 1019.51l-7.53 16.9 -11.88 27.41 -11.65 27.56 -11.46 27.83 -11.25 27.98 -11.01 28.12 -10.81 28.31 -10.63 28.51 -10.42 28.7 -10.23 28.85 -10.02 28.96c-116.33,344.34 -191.17,697.43 -252.83,1055.1l653.66 111.64c64.39,-375.46 145.6,-761.87 287.77,-1116.31 11.46,-27.84 23.16,-55.35 35.41,-82.85l-607.12 -266.71zm-470.59 2020.58c-59.56,434.17 -112.4,870.02 -185.82,1302.1l653.64 111.66c74.69,-439.32 128.58,-882.15 189.13,-1323.58l-656.95 -90.18zm-313.26 1926.44c-37.71,151.12 -80.6,298.16 -132.92,444.91 -14.75,40.29 -29.95,79.95 -45.97,119.76 -9.49,22.96 -19.13,45.73 -29.02,68.52l-19.91 44.12 -10.17 21.68 -10.25 21.33 -10.38 21.01 -10.52 20.76 -10.59 20.37 -10.72 20.06 -10.88 19.8 -10.95 19.44 -11.07 19.08 -11.21 18.81 -11.32 18.5 -11.42 18.15 -11.52 17.76 -11.63 17.46 -11.76 17.12 -11.88 16.82 -12 16.48 -12.07 16.1 -12.19 15.78 -12.33 15.47 -13.3 16.17 502.46 432.73 7.57 -8.94 18.84 -22.94 18.47 -23.17 18.15 -23.49 17.83 -23.78 17.45 -24 17.14 -24.23 16.84 -24.55 16.54 -24.79 16.23 -25.07 15.9 -25.24 15.6 -25.45 15.31 -25.7 15.04 -25.96 14.76 -26.17 14.46 -26.34 14.23 -26.62 13.95 -26.83 13.65 -26.94 13.43 -27.19 13.18 -27.41 12.9 -27.52 12.7 -27.77 12.46 -28.01 12.21 -28.13 11.97 -28.25 11.78 -28.52 11.56 -28.66 11.32 -28.81 11.12 -28.98 10.92 -29.12 10.74 -29.39 20.86 -59.09c50.53,-148.45 93.46,-296.98 131.42,-449.1l-643.01 -162.03zm-862.81 1358l-21.44 8.01 -17.36 6.01 -17.72 5.77 -17.93 5.45 -18.21 5.16 -18.57 4.86 -18.97 4.59 -19.22 4.28 -19.54 3.95 -19.95 3.65 -21.71 3.62 -21.47 3.3 -21.16 2.94 -21.08 2.63 -20.92 2.33 -20.72 2.02 -20.41 1.69 -20.27 1.39 -20.2 1.11 -19.92 0.8 -19.72 0.5 -19.59 0.22 -19.38 -0.08 -19.28 -0.36 -19.08 -0.62 -18.98 -0.92 -18.79 -1.18 -18.6 -1.45 -18.53 -1.72 -18.35 -2 -18.27 -2.26 -18.09 -2.5 -17.97 -2.78 -17.87 -3.03 -17.73 -3.29 -17.68 -3.56 -17.51 -3.78 -17.41 -4.05 -17.38 -4.31 -17.22 -4.55 -17.16 -4.81 -17.07 -5.05 -16.99 -5.3 -16.93 -5.56 -16.81 -5.8 -16.8 -6.06 -16.71 -6.3 -16.62 -6.56 -16.6 -6.8 -16.54 -7.06 -16.5 -7.32 -16.38 -7.53 -16.41 -7.83 -16.38 -8.08 -16.18 -8.25 2.7 1.43 -313.19 584.49 29.32 15.04 24.32 11.99 24.49 11.68 24.77 11.4 24.9 11.04 25.08 10.7 25.25 10.36 25.47 10.03 25.6 9.65 25.77 9.31 25.99 8.95 26.13 8.59 26.31 8.21 26.45 7.84 26.63 7.45 26.82 7.09 26.93 6.68 27.12 6.31 27.29 5.9 27.39 5.51 27.58 5.1 27.71 4.71 27.89 4.3 28 3.89 28.12 3.47 28.28 3.06 28.4 2.64 28.56 2.24 28.68 1.8 28.75 1.39 28.94 0.96 29.01 0.54 29.18 0.1 29.26 -0.31 29.42 -0.76 29.51 -1.19 29.5 -1.6 29.74 -2.04 29.87 -2.49 29.88 -2.9 29.96 -3.33 30.1 -3.77 30.31 -4.22 30.31 -4.64 30.36 -5.07 31.97 -5.85 31.74 -6.44 31.42 -6.98 31.07 -7.52 30.86 -8.09 30.6 -8.65 30.26 -9.2 29.88 -9.72 29.64 -10.28 33.61 -12.51 -235.63 -619.82zm-1457.54 -403c-205.96,-209.25 -374.06,-446.15 -528.85,-694.78 -63.42,-102.88 -123.88,-206.74 -182.63,-312.36l-580.69 320.19c227.07,409.41 488.08,815.3 817.71,1150.2l474.46 -463.25zm-1008.99 -1581.4c-194.04,-396.27 -372.38,-799.6 -564.35,-1196.34l-598.7 285.07c188.3,400.89 372.59,804.85 567.33,1202.53l595.72 -291.26z"/>
```

Black:

```
<path fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="33.34" stroke-miterlimit="22.9256" stroke-dasharray="66.680000 33.340000" d="M12.91 83.58c70.32,86.01 98.93,277.49 210.97,258.03 112.04,-19.47 49.72,-280.29 141.17,-319.21 91.45,-38.91 102.48,129.15 153.72,193.72"/>
```

So the two options, a path with a special stroke, and a series of blocks are exported as such.

[image]

My first thought would be that your render engine on Android is not capable of rendering the file, I used SVG version 1.

---

Answering your specific question, if what you have is a single curve, there is nothing to break apart, you have only one connected curve. What I did was convert the path to objects.

- Object > Convert Stroke to object
- Or press Ctrl+Shift+Q

Now you have several blocks not connected. Now you can brake those apart.

Comment: Thanks for so detailed answer, In regard to your last part, I wonder how Corel make a dashed line if it is not a series of blocks?

Comment: The stroke has a description of how should it be rendered. Any vector file is a description of how should be filled and the stroke how width, color, and style. Try editing the text of a generated SVG file.